# How to take same index element from a list with 2 lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Lets say I have the following list:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Is there a way to sum all the seconds elements **without using loop**? Such as:

```
the_sum = 0
for num in a:
    the_sum += num[1]
>>> 15
```

Comment: `sum([x[1] for x in a])` (you know there is a loop here, but you can't see it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using loop you can use `zip()` function:

```
>>> sum(list(zip(*a))[1])
15
```

*Note*: If you are using python 2.X since `zip` returns a list instead of an iterator you don't need to use `list()` on `zip` function.

Answer (score 3):

Comprehensions:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(sum(sublist[1] for sublist in a))
```

will result in

```
15
```

Answer (score 2):

Use reduce so you dont create intermediate objects in memory:

```
>>>from functools import reduce
>>>reduce(lambda x, y: x + y[1], a, 0)
>>>15
```

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are totally fine, but here's a fourth way:

```
>>> import operator
>>> sum(map(operator.itemgetter(2), a))
15
```